# Discord JS SlashCommandBuilder

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm Currently trying to implement SlashCommandBuilder into my Discord Bot.
The bot is currently using prefix '!' and I want to remake it to work with the SlashCommandBuilder, The following code is what i have used and tested, as it pretty much works fine or looks like it's working fine I'm still having an issue caused when someone uses '/hello' It will give him Error 'The application did not respond'.
I did double check the API, Token and such using a Prefix as a check.
The Code does actually add the command to the discord and it looks in the lists of commands.
I'm also splitting the commands inside 'commands' folder.

index.js :

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
    const config = require('./config.json');
    const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');  
    const client = new Client();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    client.commands = new Collection();
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
      const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
      client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
    client.once('ready', () => {
      console.log('Bot is ready!');
      const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(config.token);
      rest.put(
        Routes.applicationCommands(client.user.id),
        { body: client.commands },
      )
        .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered commands'))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
      if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
      const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
      if (!command) return;
      try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        interaction.reply({ content: 'Error executing command', ephemeral: true });
      }
    });
client.login(config.token)
```

commands/hello.js

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'hello',
  description: 'Replys with Hi',
  execute(interaction) {
    interaction.reply({ content: 'Hi!' });
  },
};
```

Please if anyone has information on why this was caused, i would love to listen.
Thank you for reading and appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: `name: 'Hello'` is not the same as `hello`

Comment: yes it is actually hello